# The serialization of a Django ArrayField escapes accented characters with too many backslashes

Tags: json, django, postgresql, encoding

Django provides us with ArrayField: a PostgreSQL specific model field which allows storing lists of [data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/).

I use it to model an Article object:

```
authors = ArrayField(models.Charfield) 
title = models.CharField
```

For example, here is an entry in the database:

- authors = {"Pierre Stévens", "Jacques Dupont"}
- title = Sur le terrain crétacé de Liège

**I would like to export all the articles as a JSON**:

```
query_set = Article.objects.all()
articles_json = serialize('json', fields('authors', 'title')
```

The serialization of the ArrayField "authors" **escapes the accented character "é" with four backslashes instead of two**. The regular "title" field is correctly escaped. Look at the difference:

```
articles_json = {"title":"Sur le terrain cr\\u00e9tac\\u00e9 de Li\\u00e9ge", "authors": "[\\"Pierre St\\\\u00e9\\", "Jacques Dupont"]"}
```

This is not understood by the client. To make it works, I just searched and replaced the string

```
articles_json = articles_json.replace('\\\\','\\')
```

I'm really not sure of this workaround. Did you experiment this problem? How did or would you solve it?

Comment: maybe it's a problem with collation in your database?

Comment: SHOW LC_COLLATE gives "C". Do you think it has to be set to "UTF8"?

Comment: I think that's a good idea. If you can't change for the whole database now, you an change only for this column.

Comment: Just saw this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38867411/5357503 may help

Comment: The collation is now set to "en_US.UTF-8" but I still do need to replace the string.

Comment: The example code calls `serialize`, but there is no indication where this comes from. Can you instead re-write the example to be a [complete, minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can try running?