# Mysql select giving the wrong answer inside php

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have this issue with a PHP script when querying a mysql DB.

The query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM theTable WHERE fieldValue = ‘Dom-Rémy'
```

I have checked that when performing by hand this query in the administration console (phpMyAdmin) I can find one record matching the request, which is what I expect.

But inside a PHP script where the code is as follows, I always get 0 records (instead of 1):

```
$Query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM theTable WHERE fieldValue = 'Dom-Rémy'";
$DBR = mysql_query($Query,$Connection);
$NBR = mysql_result($DBR,0,0);
printf("NBR: %d\n",$NBR);
```

Why is that? I suspect the european character inside the fieldValue is what causes the problem, but what should I do to make it work?

Comment: You suspect the european character inside the fieldValue causes the problem. That's easy to test. Have you done that?

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string('Dom-Rémy') before passing to sql query

Comment: Yes but that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_*` API in PHP; switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using something like this before Your query to set charset of client and results:

```
  mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn);
```

Comment: Simpler is to execute `SET NAMES ut8`.

Answer (score -1):

Use only count count(*) wont work some time

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT FROM theTable WHERE fieldValue = 'Dom-Rémy'";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: It is  count()  function.  Count is nothing.